# How do I use Python-Selenium-BS4-send keys and return varying URL

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, sendkeys

I am trying to get a hang of the webscraping with BS4. I need to input the provider name and then scrape the info after the search is done. My question is, when using input variables with Python to 'send_keys' and search, how do I write my script to always return the new URL when the input variables will change each time I input a new provider? 
All of the resources I have found online only focus on one hard coded URL to scrape from and don't have the input interaction to send keys and return a new varying URL. See my current code below.
Thanks for any guidance!

```
print('Hello! Let\s create a new provider!')
print('What is the provider\s first name?')
FirstName = input()
print('What is the provider\s last name?')
LastName = input()
print('One moment while I search!')
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://npiregistry.cms.hhs.gov/')
FirstElem = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('#id_first_name')
FirstElem[0].send_keys(FirstName)
LastElem = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('#id_last_name')
LastElem[0].send_keys(LastName)
CityElem = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('#id_city')
CityElem[0].send_keys('Fairbanks')
SearchElem = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="508focusheader"]/div[2]/div/form/div[5]/div/div/input[2]')
SearchElem[0].click()
NpiElem = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/a')
NpiElem[0].click()
```